# How to fix long running testcafe tests in CircleCI

Tags: automated-tests, e2e-testing, circleci, testcafe, circleci-2.0

I'm running my e2e TestCafe scripts in CircleCI 2.0. When I run these tests locally on my mac they take about ~3min. When they run via CircleCI, they typically take 10+ minutes.

Has anyone encountered this before?

I've tried clearing the Circle CI cache and using a different docker image (ie. image: circleci/node:8.9.4-browsers)

Answer (score 3):

Had same issue, solved it by running tests in concurrency.

My script in package.json:

```
"test": "testcafe -c 5 chrome:headless tests/back-end -r xunit:/tmp/test-results/res.xml"
```

More info here:
https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/concurrent-test-execution.html

In paid version you can configure CPU and RAM resources for each job to make them faster:
https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#resource_class

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I currently run with a concurrency of 2. If we do more than that we've seen issues arise. I will look into increasing the CPU + RAM, perhaps this may help.